# How can I tell if Jupyter Notebook cell is running?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

the stupid question probably, but when I'm using Google Colab, on the top left side there is a play button, which is moving/loading once pressed, so you can tell the cell is running.

But on the normal Jupyter Notebook installed locally you just click run on top and... Have no idea to tell if it's running or not... Is there a way I can add the play button, or somehow else tell it's still running? (See image below for better understanding)

[image: colab_vs_jupyter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's running, you will see an asterisk instead of the number
[image]

Comment: oh great, never noticed that, thanks :)